# Visual Studio 2010 Warning numbers. Where do I find them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, warnings

I suppress a few warnings, 1591 is the XML comments warning. It's not that I don't use the comments, there are some false positives.

Now to find the fact that XML comments warning is 1591 took a whole load of googling. Is there a list somewhere? Or a way to display the error number in Visual Studio itself?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641060/warning-cs1591-occurring-for-protected-members) is the "false positive" you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It honestly took me less than 5 seconds of Googling to find that, using the search terms "1591" and "visual studio". The top hit is right on the money: http://www.google.com/search?q=1591+visual+studio 
So suffice it to say, this is how I usually find them.

But they're all documented on the page you land at with the above search results: [C# Compiler Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx)

Do note that the warning numbers are often different for different languages. In particular, C#, VB.NET, and C/C++ all use different compilers and therefore all emit different error codes.

- [C# Compiler Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx)
- [C/C++ Build Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x5x43k7.aspx)

Also, it's worth noting that on VS 2008 and later, you can right-click over a warning in the "Error List" to display documentation related to that warning. This tells you the error level, the error number, and whatever other information you need.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't have the number 1591 to google with in the first place. That was the result of the googling. Thanks for the links though, In the ultimate version of Visual studio for example, there's a right click option with allows you to disable a warning there and then.

Comment: Google brings me to this answer... What do you say now?

Comment: @habakuk The top result for that search is still the MSDN article. So, I say the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 32):

The Error List hides the error and warning numbers, but if you open the **Output** panel in Visual Studio (menu : Debug > Windows > Output) and set it to **show output from Build**, you can find the warning number somewhere in the wall of text.

[image: VS2005 Build output]

You could also try building the project from the command line (using **msbuild**) which will output and highlight all error and warning numbers.

[image: msbuild output]

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one selected.  The other guy just dismissed the question.

Comment: I agree, this one at least addresses the question. The second part of the accepted answer about right-clicking doesn't work for me either, at least in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 7):

You can find a whole list of them here:

[Compiler and Warning messages for C/C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x5x43k7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

[Compiler and Warning messages for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this thread while trying to sort out how to find these in VS2015 with Beckhoff TwinCAT and found the Beckhoff-specific ones under Project->Properties, in the Compiler Warnings tab (as below in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALa5r.png)).

[screencap of TwinCAT project properties' compiler warning list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALa5r.png)